# Catching errors from NHibernate using S#arpArchitecture Transaction attribute

Tags: .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, transactions, s#arp-architecture

I'm using S#arpArchitecture's [TransactionAttribute](http://wiki.sharparchitecture.net/%28S%28if1dxr45yunexj3fu33ekmrr%29%29/ContribTransactions.ashx) and I ran into an error on insert (it turned out that my DB column was too small for the data).  But in order to figure out the actual problem, I had to remove the Transaction attribute and handle the transaction lifetime manually.  Is there a way to catch exceptions from the transaction attribute when NHibernate runs into an error condition?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transaction attribute doen't provide a way to inject your funcionality in it. It is designed just to handle transactions correctly.

If you want to manage transactions manually then IDbContext is what you need.

If you want to handle errors then different action filter should be used.